# How to quit from Linux namespace?

Tags: linux

I created a new user namespace:

```
unshare -U bash
```

How can I quit from this namespace to the parent namespace without closing the newly created namespace, in order to re-enter it afterwards?

I tried to persist it (in order to `nsenter` afterwards):

```
unshare --user=/root/uts-ns hostname
```

but it failed:

```
unshare: mount /proc/2731/ns/user on /root/uts-ns failed: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent namespaces are created by creating a bind mount – use `mount --bind` to "pin" the /proc file representing the namespace to another path. This implies that the `unshare` process needs to have root privileges relative to the initial namespace.

However, if `unshare` is creating a *user* namespace, then after entering the new namespace it *no longer* has root privileges – it's still UID 0 in the *new* namespace, but that's not mapped to "real" UID 0, so you're not allowed to create any new mounts.

You can still do it manually – first create the namespace in one terminal window, then in another terminal (outside the namespace) manually mount the namespace file. Or, do it while the 'unshare' process is in background:

```
# unshare --user &
# mount --bind /proc/$!/ns/user /root/user-ns
# kill -9 $!
```

(Also, on't mix up user namespaces and UTS namespaces.)

Comment: wait, in newwly unshared namespace UID becomes 65534 (nobody), not root

Comment: is /proc/$!/ns/user path temporary until new namespace closed ?